# CLLocationManager ignores stopUpdatingLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am calling `startUpdatingLocation()` on a `CLLocationManager`, and in the `didUpdateLocations` method I am calling `stopUpdatingLocation()` when the accuracy is less than 100m like so:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var lastLocation: CLLocation = locations.last! as! CLLocation
    var accuracy = lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy

    if (accuracy < 100) {
        locationCoordinate = lastLocation.coordinate
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        getData()
    }
}
```

However, the `didUpdateLocations` method is still called one or two times more after calling `stopUpdatingLocations()`, unless I set the `locationManager` to `nil`. Obviously, this calls my method `getData()` multiple times too, which I don't want. How can I make the `locationManager` stop without setting it equal to `nil`?

Comment: Its a common thing. Just use a bool member variable to prevent calling getData() when its not supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a bool as Mr H said above.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var lastLocation: CLLocation = locations.last! as! CLLocation
    var accuracy = lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy

    static bool flag = NO; //Or however this is done in Swift)

    if (accuracy < 100 && !flag) { //Check the flag in the condition

        locationCoordinate = lastLocation.coordinate
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        getData()

        flag = YES; //Set flag to yes here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I also faced similar issue.I solved it by setting CLLocationManagerDelegate to nil

Comment: This is the answer!